# SQL - Creating a Table with Two Timestamp Column with No Default Value

Tags: mysql

I want to create a table with two column, one "created" and one "modified", with a timestamp type.  I don't want them to have a default value. But when I create them, it automatically puts CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as default for at least one of them, and also on update.

How can I just have type timestamp with no default or on update value for any of my column?

Edit: I use MySQL

Comment: What's wrong with `CREATE TABLE (TIMESTAMP val1, TIMESTAMP val2 ...);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server, the `timestamp` type is used for row versioning, not for storing an actual date or time value.  [See MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx?queryresult=true).

You could create the columns with a `datetime` datatype and then set your `created` and `modified` values with triggers.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_SetDateCreated ON MyTable
FOR INSERT AS 
    UPDATE MyTable 
    SET created = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    WHERE MyTable.id = (SELECT Id FROM Inserted);
GO

CREATE TRIGGER trg_SetDateModified ON MyTable
FOR UPDATE AS 
    UPDATE MyTable
    SET modified = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    WHERE MyTable.id = (SELECT Id FROM Inserted);
GO
```

Comment: I use My SQL. I didn't know that I should use datetime for SQL, nor the trigger solution. Thanks!

Comment: I tried thatCREATE TRIGGER trg_SetDateCreated ON users FOR INSERT AS
UPDATE users SET us_created = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE users.us_id = ( SELECT us_id
FROM Inserted ) ; and I get a syntax error...

Comment: Ok, my solution was for SQL Server, not MySQL.  Perhaps someone else can provide the syntax for creating the equivalent triggers in MySQL.  It looks like this site would be a good place to get you started: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html

Comment: The only problem is.. if you have the exact same data going in as the original record, you'll still have the time stamp changed.